# tkinter get <ButtonRelease-1> when resizing window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am drawing an image gallery on canvas. When the window is resized I need to redraw the gallery.
I can bind the `<configure>` event to get resize notifications. But resizing the window by dragging the mouse creates too many events. I would like to store the change and only redraw the gallery when the mouse button is released.
Problem:
I cannot find a way to get a press or release event on the windows borders.
Is that possible or are the borders not actually part of the window?

Comment: How about two callbacks: When you resize, you set a flag `resizing` to true, then when the mouse button is released, you check whether that flag is true. If it is, you set it to false again and perform your action.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. As I wrote, releasing the mouse button on the windows borders (where you drag to change the size of a window) does not seem to create a release event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to know when the user releases the mouse, if they clicked it on the border of the window. The border is not part of the window, and Tkinter has very little knowledge of events outside of the widgets it creates.

The simplest solution might be to add a delay to your redrawing. In a `<Configure>` event, cancel any pending redraws, and schedule a new one to happen in one or two seconds.

```
class Application(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self._after_id = None
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.schedule_redraw)
        ...

    def schedule_redraw(self, event):
        if self._after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self._after_id)
        self._after_id = self.after(2000, self.redraw)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing something like that by polling from a thread. Tkinters after function looks a lot simpler. And thanks for answering the actual question about the borders.